# Error reading JSON file in Bundle layout in D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, bundle-layout

I am trying to create a bundle layout using D3.js.

I am following code at [this location](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999):

[image]

I got sample json file from [here](http://testprogramming.googlecode.com/svn-history/r391/trunk/javascript/svg/d3/test/flare-imports.json). It works fine.

Now when I try to use my json file, it gives me following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
```

My json file looks like this:

```
[
{"name":"flare.analytics.A","size":3938,"imports":["flare.analytics.B,flare.analytics.C"]},
{"name":"flare.analytics.B","size":3812,"imports":["flare.analytics.C,flare.analytics.D"]},
{"name":"flare.analytics.C","size":3812,"imports":["flare.analytics.D,flare.analytics.E"]},
{"name":"flare.analytics.D","size":743, "imports":["flare.analytics.E,flare.analytics.F"]},
{"name":"flare.analytics.E","size":3534,"imports":["flare.analytics.F,flare.analytics.G"]},
{"name":"flare.analytics.F","size":5731,"imports":["flare.analytics.G,flare.analytics.H"]},
{"name":"flare.analytics.G","size":7840,"imports":["flare.analytics.H,flare.analytics.I"]},
{"name":"flare.analytics.H","size":5914,"imports":["flare.analytics.I,flare.analytics.A"]},
{"name":"flare.analytics.I","size":3416,"imports":["flare.analytics.B,flare.analytics.A"]}
]
```

Can anybody let me know what is the problem with my json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need quotes to encapsulate the different dependents and dependencies in your json, e.g.

```
flare.analytics.A","size":3938,"imports":["flare.analytics.B","flare.analytics.C"]}...
```

rather than

```
flare.analytics.A","size":3938,"imports":["flare.analytics.B,flare.analytics.C"]}
```

See it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/59m3t/).

[image]

Comment: Just a quick question, not totally related with this but i was playing around with this d3 example and I am just wondering what the "size" parameter does in the example. When i change the parameter is as no effect. Just curious. Thanks in advance.